# jQuery Datatable shows the same button name for two distinct buttons that I want to create

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to attach two buttons to each row in Datatable like this:

```
<td>@element.LastUpdatedDate</td>
<td><button onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteRole", "Admin", new { MemberRoleId = element.MemberRoleId })'">Delete Role</button></td>
<td><button onclick="location.href= '@Url.Action("GetReportsByRole", "Admin", new { MemberRoleId = element.MemberRoleId })'">Get Reports For This Role</button></td>
```

My script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#roleTable').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "data": "LastUpdatedDate" },
            { "data": "" },
            { "data": "" }
        ]
});
```

Something weird happens: in the html page both buttons are displayed as "Get Reports For This Role". Inspecting the Elements tells me that both buttons have the value "Get Reports For This Role," yet viewing the page source shows that both buttons have distinct values. What's going on? Is this a bug of Datatable?

Comment: Try remove the `columns` section. It is unnecessary / redundant when you render out the table content by script.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if I don't add the columns, the features of Datatable are not rendered for some reason @davidkonrad